# how to write output in csv file or excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have one csv file which contains 6 columns ..THis is same data on which I am Performing operation.

```
16  28-Sep-17   9700    291.8   291.8   9964.4
17  28-Sep-17   9700    186.3   186.3   9872.6
18  28-Sep-17   9700    166.6   166.6   9871.5
24  28-Sep-17   9800    227.5   227.5   9952.2
25  28-Sep-17   9800    202.55  202.55  9916.2
```

So I want TV and tv into another file...in this format shown below..

```
9700                             ** 9800**
TV/tv                            **TV/tv**
TV/tv                            **TV/tv**
```

I did add `writer = writerow()` and all but it is plotting things weirdly...

For Column name, I add this condition `C > 21` where `C` will plot when "9700" changes into 9800 happen....till then it should add data under that Column header....

I m getting output like this ...

```
9700 
47.65
33.8
53.75
43.95
,,9800
68.2
49
76
62.3
```

Hope you guys understood

```
import csv

out = open('G:\out1.csv','w') 
with open('G:\outpuop.csv', 'r+') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(out)
y = list(reader)         
L = len(y)
A = []
M = 0
c = 1

for x in range(1,L):
    if c > 21:
        print float(y[x][2])

        c = 1

    if (float(y[x][2])) > (float(y[x][5])) : 
        if ((float(y[x][4])) != 0 ):
           TV = (float(y[x][4])) - ((float(y[x][2])) - (float(y[x][5])))
           print TV
           M = TV + M
           c = c + 1

           A.append(TV)                  
           writer.writerow(A)

        else:
           TV = (float(y[x][3])) - ((float(y[x][2])) - (float(y[x][5])))
           print TV
           M = TV + M
           c = c + 1
           A.append(TV)                  
           writer.writerow(A)

    else:
        if ((float(y[x][4])) != 0 ):
            tv = (float(y[x][4])) 
            print tv
            M = tv + M
            c = c + 1
            A.append(TV)                  
            writer.writerow(A)

        else:
             tv = (float(y[x][3])) 
             print tv
             M = tv + M
             c = c + 1
             A.append(TV)                  
             writer.writerow(A)

print M
```

Comment: Hey!, welcome to stack overflow. Try to isolate your problem and write something that is easy to grasp. Your question involves data we don't have and we can't see the expected output. I'd recommend reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, your writer will not work because the file is closed at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: @AntonvBR hey explained with data...and what I want...Hope I did explain well...

Comment: @blakev I will move that writer after `with` but not getting desire output.

Comment: Please show the exact output you should get for the data you have given. What calculations are you trying to do on the data?

Comment: @MartinEvans  I am doing if  `c3 > c6` then 
 `if c5 != 0 [ c5 - ( c3-c6) ]` else [ c4 - (c3-c6)  ] 
else  `if c5 !=0 [ c5] else [ c4] `
this calculation i m doing and getting output like this 9700 
47.65
33.8
53.75
43.95
,,9800
68.2
49
76
62.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you have a CSV that looks like:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
16,28-Sep-17,9700,291.8,291.8,9964.4
17,28-Sep-17,9700,186.3,186.3,9872.6
18,28-Sep-17,9700,166.6,166.6,9871.5
24,28-Sep-17,9800,227.5,227.5,9952.2
25,28-Sep-17,9800,202.55,202.55,9916.2
```

This script will read the file in and create individual lists based on the third column. It will then transpose the lists so that the data can be written out a row at a time (as is needed when writing a CSV file):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

models = defaultdict(list)

with open('outpuop.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        # Convert c3 to c6 into floats
        row[2:6] = map(float, row[2:6])

        if row[2] > row[5]:
            if row[4] != 0:
                TV = row[4] - (row[2] - row[5])
                models[row[2]].append(TV)
            else:
                TV = row[3] - (row[2] - row[5])
                models[row[2]].append(TV)
        else:
            tv = row[4]
            models[row[2]].append(tv)


columns = sorted(models.keys())
data = [[int(column)] + ["{:.2f}".format(v) for v in models[column]] for column in columns]

with open('out1.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerows(izip_longest(*data, fillvalue=''))
```

This will create an output CSV file containing:

```
9700,9800
291.80,227.50
186.30,202.55
166.60,
```

`models` uses a dictionary of lists to hold the `TV` information. This then gets converted into `data` by first getting a list of all the dictionary keys and sorting them. For each key, a list is made starting with the key name and then appended with all the elements for that key. Whilst doing this, each float is converted back to a string with only 2 decimal places.

`data` now holds all the information needed to write back to the file but it is in column order. The file needs to be written in row order. Furthermore, each column can be a different length. The trick to solve this is to use `izip_longest()` passing it all the data a seperate values (by using `*`). This has the effect of transposing the data, i.e. converting a list of columns into a list of rows. The `writerows()` function can ten write all the data to an output file in a single call. Note, if the normal `zip()` was used, it would stop at the point the column was longer than another. `izip_longest()` keeps going adding `fillvalue` for any missing elements, in this case an empty string.

Comment: sir I am performing an operation on that csv file and getting output in symbol  `TV` nd `tv` ...output format right now is like this 
9700 
47.65
33.8
53.75
43.95
9800
68.2
49
76
62.3   so want this into another excel or csv file like u shown...

Comment: For the data you have given, I cannot understand your result. I have updated the script as well as I can.

Comment: Thank sir appreciate it

Comment: It did sir ...thank you so much...seems like magic to me.. :)

Comment: Thank you for an explanation. Really appreciate it .